# SELECT only values THAT are different

Tags: mysql, select

I have two instances user1 and user2. They have colors

```
u_id | color<br>
  1  | red<br>
  1  | green<br>
  2  | red<br>
  2  | blue<br>
```

I need a mysql request, that will returns only distinct colors for both users

Result example:

```
u_id | color<br>
 1   |  green<br>
 2   |  blue<br>
```

Comment: I've changed the tags of the question, as it's related to a SELECT statement in MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean with "only distinct colors for both users"? Why isn't 'Red' returned?

Comment: Hm... realy, why? May be because it is the same, not distinct? Means, that red is present in both users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :

```
select u_id, color, count(*) as total from table group by u_id, color having total = 1;
```

Comment: Your example works correct, I made some modifications for fetching colors only for exact users. Thanks!
SELECT u_id, color
FROM colorinfo 
WHERE u_id in ('2', '3') 
GROUP BY color 
HAVING count(*) = 1;

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b46c4/2/0 - live example

Comment: @Ixtinkt If this answer is good, then up-vote it or mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is the example of SQL Server

```
        CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo (u_id int,color varchar(10))

        INSERT INTO  tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo VALUES(1,'red')
        INSERT INTO  tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo VALUES(1,'green')
        INSERT INTO  tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo VALUES(2,'red')
        INSERT INTO  tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo VALUES(2,'blue')


        SELECT  A.*
        FROM tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo A LEFT JOIN tempdb.dbo.##colorinfo B
        ON A.color=B.Color AND A.u_id<>b.U_ID
        WHERE B.u_id IS NULL
```

Comment: And if I whant to fetch data only for several users, where I have to inject WHERE u_id in ('1', '2')?

Comment: @SandeepKumar, you can "fiddle" with MySQL at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if you don't have it installed. No need to post a SQL-Server answer for a MySQL question. The syntax is not much different (if at all) for simple queries.